# How to integrate Sqlite to Visual Studio?

Tags: sqlite

I'm planning to use Sqlite but I don't know how to integrate it to visual studio or use it. Any help please... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend using System.Data.Sqlite ( http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com).
Have been using it for quite some time and it works great every time! You can create tables using the designer, similar to for MSSQL etc. Recommended++

Comment: @OskarKjellin: I tried downloading and installing Syste.Data.Sqlite .. but still can't see it when attempting to add new Data Connection!! .. just wondering, by integrating the sqlite, i will be able to include the header sqlite3.h, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to use it. The easiest is to get the **amalgamation** version - this version "*contains all preprocessed C code combined into a single source file*", meaning you have a single .h and .c file to add to your project. This is the officially recommended practice.

If you want to build a "proper" library or link against SQLite dynamically, you have a bit more work ahead, since there's no VS project/solution files included with SQLite. You'll have to set up your own library project, add the correct files from the sqlite-source-x.y.z.zip file, and set this project as a dependency on your main project. Doing this is actually officially discouraged.

### EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the above solution is assuming C/C++, as OP didn't specify language.

Answer (score 0):

use [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET provider for SQLite.